# Trying to configure autologin for Ubuntu 12.04 as XBMC

Tags: xbmc

I have installed 12.04 from the minimal iso and installed XBMC.

Since then I have edited: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

to say:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=xbmc
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=XBMC
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

However I still get prompted for a password at boot.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

There are GUI settings for this. Go to settings and then Users. Find the account and set it to automatically log in. Then go to the login screen and log into the account as XBMC (not Unity). When it logs in at boot, it will select the last used setting (XBMC).

You could also have it boot into Unity and then launch XBMC. In that account, search for the Startup Applications program and add the command 'XBMC'. I do it this way so that I can have better control over the display settings (XBMC's display settings didn't work).